# pass DATETIME,VARCHAR parameter as input to store procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client. My store procedure has input like this:

```
   PROCEDURE PRC_ABCED 
   (resultset_out out TYPES.cursorType, parametername IN date, 
   parametername2 IN date, parametername3 in varchar);
```

My code has DATETIME,VARCHAR parameter like

```
  public static IEnumerable<Alarm> ABCDEF(DateTime startDate, DateTime stopDate,string MonitoredBy)
```

And I want to pass it as input parameter of my store procedure like

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add("parametername", OracleDbType.Date, startDate, ParameterDirection.Input);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("parametername2", OracleDbType.Date, stopDate, ParameterDirection.Input);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("parametername3", OracleDbType.Varchar2, MonitoredBy, ParameterDirection.Input);
```

Will it ok to pass parameter like that or do i have to do something else?pls help

Comment: are you getting the expected output?

Comment: According to [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleParameterCollectionClass.htm#i1013496) it seems Ok to me.

Comment: I don't know C# but where do you handle the refcursor (first parameter, `resultset_out`)?